# String.Split to include spaces or special character

Tags: vb.net, split, textbox

Let’s say that this is my string:

**Sam, III , Adams**

Here *Sam, III* is first name and *Adams* is the the Last Name, I wanna separate first name and last name. For that I did:

```
txtbox.Text.Split(",")
```

But it is separating Sam, III, Adams into 3 parts. Can someone let me know how to separate first name and last name if we any extra ',' in either first name or last name?

Comment: The usual way to handle commas in a given field in a CSV file is to surround them with double quotes - i.e, `"Sam, III", Adam`.  In that case, you can use a CSV parser (`TextFieldParser` is a good one) to handle the mix of quoted and unquoted fields.

Comment: Can you count on the fact that there won't ever be commas in the last name? (It sounds like not.) Lots of problems like this are easy for a human. If this is that, your first step should be to spell out exactly what you would do to process the incoming data. Once you have explicit English instructions, converting them to code is much easier.

Comment: Is it possible to give some sample.. I never used TextFieldParser before.. Thanks @Tim

Answer (score 0):

Instead of String.Split you could use [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the index of the first comma and then [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the parts on either side of the comma:

```
    Dim text = "Sam, III, Adams"
    Dim index = text.IndexOf(",")
    Dim firstName = text.Substring(0, index)
    Dim secondName = text.Substring(index + 1)
```

Comment: From what the question stated, I would assume you meant to use LastIndexOf() there as what you currently have is `Sam`   and  `III, Adams`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have little bit worry,, because my first name and last name fields in db has more than one comma(',') in some records... there is no unique rule about how many comma's..  if we 2 comma's in both first name and last name, how can i separate those... if we separate first name and last name with extra spaces  both sides of comma(,), can we do this way??

Comment: @Knowledge2Share I don't think there's a fail safe automatic way of handling commas in either the first name or the second name or both. One option would be to automatically convert based on the most frequent scenario and then manually identify and fix the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

> In *either* first name or last name

Simple answer: no. "Sam, III, Adams" - is that "Sam III" "Adams" or "Sam" "III Adams" - how can the application possibly know other than knowing all possible names or variations for the comma part. I'm guessing this person's name would actually be "Sam Adams, the Third" - not sure why their *first name* would be "Sam III".

The comments to another answer suggest you do have specific rules to use when there are commas - if you can state the requirements clearly when there are multiple commas, then a more specific answer can be provided,

It appears that you may need a set of rules, based on how many commas, eg:

```
    Dim firstname = ""
    Dim surname = ""

    Dim text = "Sam, III, Adams"
    Dim parts = text.Split(",")

    If parts.Length = 1 Then
        firstname = ""
        surname = parts(0)
    else If parts.Length = 2 Then
        firstname = parts(0)
        surname = parts(1)
    else If parts.Length = 3 Then
       ' Rule from question sample, comma in firstname (makes no sense to me, but that's how it's in the question)
        firstname = parts(0) + ", " + parts(1)
        surname = parts(2)
    else If parts.Length = 4 Then
        firstname = parts(0) + ", " + parts(1)
        surname = parts(2) + ", " + parts(3)
    End If
```

(or use a `select case`)

If you can simplify the rules, then it's much cleaner, eg:

All commas in surname:

```
firstname = string.Join(", ", parts.Take(parts.length-1))
surname = parts(parts.length)
```

All commas in firstname:

```
firstname = parts(0)
surname = string.Join(", ", parts.Skip(1))
```